# How to send a notification into Microsoft Teams activity feed from external source

Tags: office365, botframework, microsoft-teams

Is there a way to send a notification into *Activity Feed* of Microsoft Teams from external source?

I have found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/activity-feed#rest-api-sample) link but it seems like it will generate notification only when user posts a message into channel.

Can we build a service that can push notifications into *Activity Feed* of Microsoft Teams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the activity feed, you will need to use a [Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-overview). Also, you can send notification only for message/card sent in 1:1 chat conversation.

If your bot posts cards/messages into a channel, they'll automatically show up in the user's feed if he or she has followed that channel.

Sample code to [Starting personal conversations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#starting-personal-conversations)

```
        var parameters = new ConversationParameters
        {
            Members = new ChannelAccount[] { new ChannelAccount(userId) },
            ChannelData = new TeamsChannelData
            {
                Tenant = new TenantInfo(tenantId),
                Notification = new NotificationInfo() { Alert = true }
            }
        };

         MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl, DateTime.MaxValue);
        var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        var response = await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks Wajeed. I've some questions-
1. Can you please share an example of Bot Framework API (C#) where I can set "alert" property to true, as mentioned in below link?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/activity-feed
2. Can we invoke Bot from any external service and let it post a message/card?

Comment: Yes, both are possible. Update the answer with C# code. You can call this code in a different endpoint like api/SendProactive message.

Comment: Thanks Wajeed. Can you please share me links where I can understand this code in details? A step by step guide would be much appreciated. 
Especially I need to understand what is *userId*, *tenantId* and *serviceUrl* in this code.

Comment: Here is link with detailed explaination: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#starting-personal-conversations. Added same in answer as well.

Comment: Thanks Wajeed. It was helpful. Accepted your answer.

Comment: Can you please have a look at below question I posted recently?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168754/apis-for-reading-activity-feed-from-microsoft-teams